# What is a example showing that the tree-based variant for the greedy best-first search is incomplete?

Tags: comparison, search, best-first-search, tree-search, graph-search

I understand that a tree-based variant will have nodes repeatedly added to the frontier. How do I craft an example where a particular goal node is never found. Is this example valid.

[image]

On the other hand, how do I explain that the graph-based version of the greedy best-first search is complete?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Do you know the difference between tree search and graph search? If not, please, read [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/9554/2444).